# To avoid e + and - as input on the wpf numericupdown control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a wpf based tool which has a numericupdown control to increase/decrease the number of hardwares.

The max number would be around 250. so I need to keep textbox part for the user to enter the number.

But i saw that it accepts "e" "+" "-" as well.
I want only numbers to be passed there and avoid e,+ and - in the textbox part of the control. Is it possible?

I am new to wpf so seeking for some help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could just set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties.

Comment: i have set min as 1 and max as 250. but when the user types, it accepts e, + and -

Comment: What's the problem with that? It will filter out the "-" and people using "+" and "e" is extremely rare.

Comment: yes, but the UI testers are not accepting it, they say it should behave in the similar way like how it behaves when any user try to type alphabets (nothing appears)

Comment: But it's *not* the alphabet. "-", "+", and "e" are all parts of valid numerical input. By their logic, you should prevent users from typing in numbers as well because those characters exist on the keyboard.